# matching groups of rows in two databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following (simplified) situation in two databases:

```
    ID       Prog      T         Qt   
|---------|--------|---------|---------|  
|   a     |    1   |   N     |   100   |  
|   b     |    1   |   Y     |   10    |  
|   b     |    2   |   N     |   90    |  
|   c     |    1   |   N     |   25    |  
|   c     |    2   |   Y     |   25    |  
|   c     |    3   |   Y     |   25    |  
|   c     |    4   |   Y     |   25    |  
|---------|--------|---------|---------|
```

---

```
    ID       Prog      T         Qt   
|---------|--------|---------|---------|  
|   1     |    1   |   Y     |   10    |  
|   1     |    2   |   N     |   90    |  
|   2     |    1   |   Y     |   100   |  
|   3     |    1   |   Y     |   100   |  
|   4     |    1   |   Y     |    50   |  
|   4     |    2   |   Y     |    25   |  
|   4     |    3   |   Y     |    25   |      
|---------|--------|---------|---------|
```

I need to compare groups of rows (primary keys are ID and Prog), to find out which groups of rows represent the same combination of factors (not considering ID).

In the example above, ID "b" in the first table and ID "1" in the second have the same combination of values for Prog, T and Qt, while no one else can be considered exactly the same between the 2 dbs (while ID "2" and "3" in the second table are equal, I'm not interested in comparing in the same db).

I hope I explained everything.

Comment: @iamdave my command of SQL isn't as good as it should be to try anything more than a few SELECT statement. I think I should use a function or a stored procedure, to fetch possible results over all the IDs in the first table, rather than have to resort to a series of SELECT * FROM ... JOIN ... ON ... WHERE ... The truth is, I've searched something around this site and elsewhere, but no one seems to have shared anything on the topic. There are 2 dozens of values to match, so I was searching for something neat and elegant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A join and aggregation should work for this purpose:

```
select t1.id, t2.id
from (select t1.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from t1
     ) t1 join
     (select t2.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.prog = t2.prog and t1.T = t2.T and t1.Qt = t2.Qt and t1.cnt = t2.cnt
group by t1.id, t2.id, t1.cnt
having count(*) = t1.cnt;
```

This is a little tricky.  The subqueries count the number of rows for each id in each table.  The `on` clause gets matches between the three columns -- and checks that the ids have the same count.  The `group by` and `having` then get rows where number of matching rows is the total number of rows.

Comment: Thank Gordon, you are right: I was pretty sure for each combination of the first table I should check only those combinations with the same number of rows. I'll have a look at it. As I wrote to Wes H, I would love to find something more elegant than joining on 2 dozens of values, but if SQL has nothing better I'll go with either one!

Comment: @MaZe . . . In other databases, you an use `listagg()`, `group_concat()` or something similar.  Although you *could* do this in SQL Server, it is probably even less elegant that this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Join the two tables on the conditions you want to match.  The results will be the values that match between them.

```
CREATE TABLE a (ID CHAR(1), Prog INT, T CHAR(1), Qt INT);
CREATE TABLE b (ID int, Prog INT, T CHAR(1), Qt INT);

    INSERT INTO dbo.a
            ( ID ,Prog ,T ,Qt)
    VALUES  ('a',1,'N',100), ('b',1,'Y',10), ('b',2,'N',90),('c',1,'N',25),('c',2,'Y',25),('c',3,'Y',25),('c',4,'Y',25)
    INSERT INTO dbo.b
            ( ID ,Prog ,T ,Qt)
    VALUES  (1,1,'Y',10),(1,2,'N',90),(2,1,'Y',100),(3,1,'Y',100),(4,1,'Y',50),(4,2,'Y',25),(4,3,'Y',25)

WITH CTEa
AS (SELECT  ID,
            Prog,
            T,
            Qt,
            Cnt = COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
    FROM    dbo.a
   ),
     CTEb
AS (SELECT  ID,
            Prog,
            T,
            Qt,
            Cnt = COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
    FROM    dbo.b
   )
SELECT  ID_A = a.ID,
        ID_B = b.ID,
        b.Prog,
        b.T,
        b.Qt,
        b.Cnt
FROM    CTEa AS a
  INNER JOIN CTEb AS b
    ON a.Prog = b.Prog
       AND  a.T = b.T
       AND  a.Qt = b.Qt
       AND  a.Cnt = b.Cnt;
```

Results:

```
ID_A    ID_B    Prog    T   Qt  Cnt
b       1       1       Y   10  2
b       1       2       N   90  2
```

Comment: This is useful, I suspected it could be a lot of work to join on 2 dozens of values, but in case there's nothing else better I'll go with either this one or the Gordon Linoff solution. Thanks!

Comment: @MaZe I thought that `c` and `4` shouldn't match.

Comment: @SqlZim you are totally right. I hadn't checked in full the result table, only "b" and "1" are the same. In fact, now that I see, what makes Gordon solution better is exactly the fact that he checks for the same number of rows. Thanks for letting me see it!

Comment: @MaZe  I've updated the query to fix the condition I overlooked.

Comment: @SqlZim good catch.  I missed that c and 4 should'nt be part of it.  I've updated the query to fix that.